# How to register a key down event in League of Legends? C#

Tags: c#, autokey

I made one in Obj-C (a project that auto presses keys for me in League) and it was quite easy. Now I'm making one for windows but I'm having trouble.
SendKeys.SendWait was my first attempt. It allowed me to type in the chat box but it wouldn't work to activate abilities.
Then I tried SendInput which works in Notepad but doesn't register keys in League of Legends.

I've tried many frameworks.
[Here](https://github.com/GanMatt/LeagueAutoKeyPresser)'s my code and many failed attempts.

I figure there's a way to do it because I've seen auto clickers that can. Can you figure out what I'm doing wrong or do you have code that can auto press keys within games?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I used the AutoIT DLL and it gave me everything I needed for the task.

Message me if you're interested in the source. I made the program for both Mac and Windows.